# Solve $\cos x + \sqrt 3\sin x = \frac{\sqrt 3 -1}{\sqrt 2}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $\cos x + \sqrt 3 \sin x = \frac{\sqrt 3 -1}{\sqrt 2}, -\pi \leq x \leq \pi$

I tried to solve this equation as follows:

$2 \cos (x-\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt 3 -1}{\sqrt 2}$

$\implies \cos (x-\frac{\pi}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt 3 -1}{2\sqrt 2}$

$\implies \cos (x-\frac{\pi}{3}) = \cos (\frac{5 \pi}{12})$

$\implies x = \frac{5 \pi}{12}+\frac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi$

So, one value of $x$ is $\frac{3 \pi}{4}$

It can't be $\frac{7 \pi}{4}$ because this is greater than $\pi$. But, $\frac{7 \pi}{4}$ is the same as $\frac{- 3 \pi}{4}$. So, I thought $\frac{- 3 \pi}{4}$ should be a solution. I also tried to get another set of values by the following:

$ x = \pi - \frac{5 \pi}{12}+\frac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi$

To verify my solution, I [graphed](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tukks8khv6) it in desmos. None of the solutions seem right? Where am I going wrong? In general, I am able to solve a trig equation till the last step. However, I seem to face difficulties in finding all $x$ that satisfy a given trig. equation. I would be thankful if anyone pointed me towards some useful resources that may help.

Comment: You typed the wrong equation. The denominator has an extra factor of $2$. As an extra thing to note, if $\cos(x) = y$, then $x = \pm\arccos(y)+2\pi k$. (Remember that cosine is even.) This means $x = \pm \dfrac{5\pi}{12}+\dfrac{\pi}{3}+2\pi k$.

Comment: (Continuing my previous comment...) What you tried at the end would be correct for arcsine, not arccosine. If $\sin(x) = y$, then $x = \arcsin(y)+2\pi k$ or $x = \pi-\arcsin(y)+2\pi k$. This all goes back to $\sin(\pi-x) = \sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. thank you so much. Post your comments as an answer if you don't mind, they clear all my doubts :)

Comment: No problem. :-) I'll add the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typed the wrong equation. The denominator has an extra factor of $2$.

Your actual work was correct, until the last two steps. In general, note that $\sin(\pi-x) = \sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

Going in reverse, this means:

1. If $\sin(x) = y$, then $x = \arcsin(y)+2\pi k$ or $x = \pi-\arcsin(y)+2\pi k$.
2. If $\cos(x) = y$, then $x = \pm\arccos(y)+2\pi k$

So, for your general solution here, you'll have $x = \pm\dfrac{5\pi}{12}+\dfrac{\pi}{3} + 2k \pi$. Notice that what you did would've been the right thing if you had arcsine, but that's not the case here.

Of course, the problem isn't asking for a general solution for $k \in \mathbb Z$, but this point is still important nonetheless. I also thought this might help, given that you said about these problems. If you remember those two points, the general solution will be simple to obtain, so all that's left is using the domain that you're given.

Answer (score 1):

I have been hit by insight, but for me to pull it off I have to think way outside the box.

Firstly, I'll type in degrees because they're easier to type.

Second, I'm dividing everything by 2.

$\cos x \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{2} \cdot \sin x = \dfrac{\sqrt 3 -1}{\sqrt 2} \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}$

$\cos x \sin \dfrac{\pi}{6}+ \cos \dfrac{\pi}{6} \sin x = \dfrac{\sqrt 6 -\sqrt{2}}{4}$

$\sin{(x+\frac{\pi}{6})}=\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{12}}$

$x+\dfrac{\pi}{6}=\dfrac{\pi}{12}$

$x=2\pi n-\dfrac{\pi}{12} \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\sin{(x+\frac{\pi}{6})}=\sin{\dfrac{11\pi}{12}}$

$x+\dfrac{\pi}{6}=\dfrac{11\pi}{12}$

$x=\dfrac{3\pi}{4}+2\pi n \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$

Now this is where I defend myself. How do I know that $\dfrac{\sqrt 6 -\sqrt{2}}{4}=\sin \dfrac{\pi}{12}^c$

Consider the double angle formula for cosine. If used to operate on $15°$, you would get the cosine of $30°$ which is elementary.

$1-2\sin^2{\alpha} =\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \quad \alpha = \{15°, 195°\}$

$a=\sin \alpha$

$1-2a^2=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$2a^2=1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$a^2=\dfrac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}=\dfrac{8-4\sqrt{3}}{16}$

$\sqrt{8-4\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{6-2\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt{3}+2}=\sqrt{\sqrt{6}(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})-\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})^2}$

$a=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$

$\sin{15°}=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$

You might wonder if there's any point in doing this. Technically I already knew this but I think there's more to answering a question than the answer. What you discover on the way is totally worth it.